# The best way to use conditionally dependencies in Gradle for Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, dependencies

Info: Using Gradle 2.14 on Windows 7 to build JAVA multi-projects.

When I'm building on my machine i want to use the libraries/subprojects on my machine.
When Jenkins is building the project, he shall use the libraries/subprojects from my repo.

So I made a "JenkinsTask" that just exist for my IF statement. This is already almost working  the way I want it. Here the code from my root project gradle script:

```
task JenkinsTask() {
//doing nothing
}

def ProjectB_Version //defined on command line

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
if (taskGraph.hasTask(JenkinsTask)) {
    println "Archiva dependency"
            dependencies {
            compile group: 'Lib_ProjectB', name: 'ProjectB', version: ProjectB_Version
    }
} 
else {
    println "Filesystem dependency"
            dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'ProjectB\\build\\libs', includes: ['*.jar'])
    }       
}
}
compileJava.dependsOn ":ProjectB:build"
```

On my machine I just run `gradle build -PProjectB_Version=0.5`

On Jenkins I run `gradle :build jenkinstask -x :ProjectB:build -PProjectB_Version=0.5`

Now the question is if there is a "gradle" way to do this? So I wouldn't need the if/else statement and maybe even could relinquish the "-x" paramater Jenkins command line. Especially the "Jenkinstask" feels like a hack.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's considered as a gradle way, but I think you should declare dependencies in the same way regardless of who builds the project and where.
Instead I think you should:

1. define artifacts repositories depending on the build environment,
2. base decision on a command line argument instead of checking for a task in the task execution graph.

This way you will be able to have automatic pom generation for your project locally as well because for that gradle needs to know artifact group and name. And the build script would look cleaner in my opinion.

Just place something like this somewhere before all your tasks:

```
if (project.hasProperty('jenkins')) {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${jenkinsRepoUrl}"
        }
    }
} else {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile (
        ['commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4'],
        ["Lib_ProjectB:ProjectB:${ProjectB_Version}"],
    }
}
```

And run the build as `gradle clean build -PProjectB_Version=0.5` locally and as `gradle clean build -Pjenkins -PProjectB_Version=0.5 -PjenkinsRepoUrl=https://nexuscn.my-company.com/content/repositories/main` on Jenkins.

P.S.: I would declare the `ProjectB_Version` property in project gradle.properties instead since your code is likely to depend on the actual version API.